# Wrong json_encode on PHP

Tags: php, json

I Have a simple script is like this.

```
<?php
    $uri = file_get_contents('http://lewatmana.com/peta/pois/');
    $json = json_decode($uri, true);
    for($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
        $response['url'][$i] =  $json[$i]['name']; 
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

I think this script will work as well as I thought, but I am wrong, this script produces the wrong JSON output, where this JSON output cannot be decoded.

**OUTPUT**

```
{"url":["Alternatif Cibubur"]}{"url":["Alternatif Cibubur","Ancol - Bandara"]}{"url":["Alternatif Cibubur","Ancol - Bandara","Ancol - Tj.Priok"]}..........................
```

I Try to decode this JSON output to JSON Decode Online, but the response is **Invalid JSON format!! Unable to process your request.**
is there any suggestion where this script error?
Thank You

Comment: `echo json_encode($response)` is inside the loop. You only need it one and after the loop

Comment: Make your `json_encode` outside of your `for` loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce _one_ json string. It's producing one json string per iteration of the for loop, so you're echoing multiple strings

Comment: thank you, its work

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will always produce a valid json string. There is a problem with your code. You are basically echoing multiple json string. You should just echo once after loop is finished. Eg:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
    $response['url'][$i] =  $json[$i]['name'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for my own entertainment and in the spirit of *how short can I make this code if I didn't bother about readability*...

```
$uri = file_get_contents('http://lewatmana.com/peta/pois/');
echo json_encode(['url' => array_column(json_decode($uri, true), 'name')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are doing echo in loop. change your code as below

```
<?php
$uri = file_get_contents('http://lewatmana.com/peta/pois/');
$json = json_decode($uri, true);
for($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
$response['url'][$i] =  $json[$i]['name']; 
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```